# How can this function be returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This seems so simple but I just don't get it. Why when I pass b and c through the function below, and the if statement returns true, and I use a return statement, I get undefined?

```
function stockList(arr1, arr2){
  arr1.forEach(function(elB){
     for (var elC in arr2){
       if (elB.charAt(0) === arr2[elC]){
        return "hello"
       }
     }
  })
}

b = ["ABAR 200", "CDXE 500", "BKWR 250", "BTSQ 890", "DRTY 600"]
c = ["A", "B"]

stockList(b,c)
```

I expect the result to be "hello" but I get undefined. I have a feeling I'm going to hit my head and go "doh" when I discover the problem. Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't return anything. Use two `for` loops, and maybe add a catch-all `return` at then end of the function too:

```js
function stockList(arr1, arr2) {
  for (var elB in arr1) {
    for (var elC in arr2) {
      if (arr1[elB].charAt(0) === arr2[elC]) {
        return "hello"
      }
    }
  }
  return "goodbye";
}

b = ["ABAR 200", "CDXE 500", "BKWR 250", "BTSQ 890", "DRTY 600"]
c = ["A", "B"]

console.log(stockList(b, c));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning hello from an inner function: the forEach.
If you want to return hello from the main function, do not use a forEach, use a simple for loop.

Comment: OK, I get the downvote. I see the duplicate now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53526325/why-is-this-javascript-function-returning-undefined. I'll be more careful in the future.